# Configure NHibnerate SQL string cache with Spring.NET

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

With memory profiling tools, it looks like NHibnerate will cache SQL strings while execution, which occupy a large # of memory spaces.

Whether Spring.NET is able to configure the cache-related setting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring.NET doesn't provide any (direct) control of that specific NHibernate behavior, but since Spring.NET permits access to all underlying NHibernate settings, if there is a 'native' way to control this behavior in NHibernate, then passing this config value to NH when using Spring.NET is entirely supported.

For more info, see http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup and investigate closely the pattern of setting NH properties by adding dictionary entries as demonstrated in the code sample.  This approach permits access to any and all underlying 'native' NHibernate settings that you may need to control/configure when using NH with Spring.NET.